# JdbcTemplate problems with nested queries

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to use nested queries with JdbcTemplate but found the issue, it seems to me that it's doesn't suppot nested queries.. Am i right? or what i need to change?

So, i invoke

```
 getJdbcTemplate().query(request, new Object[]{name}...) 
 // request is query which you can see in error message
```

which gives results in oracle but failes with

> org.springframework.jdbc.InvalidResultSetAccessException: PreparedStatementCallback; invalid ResultSet access for SQL **[select sq.name as name from (select t1.name as name   from table1 t1 left outer join table2 t2 on t2.id  = t1.fk_id   where t1.name is not null ) sq where upper(name) like upper('?')]**; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index

EDITED

request is a simple String object which is actually an sql that you see in exception message. The eturn object has no matter in this situation as i left it empty (for testing ourpose)

but just for you to be sure here it is:

```
List<MyObject> list = getJdbcTemplate().query(request, new Object[]{"Somename"}, new RowMapper() {
           public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
               return new MyObject();
           }
       });
```

Comment: What is `request`? What type of object is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the `upper('?')` to `upper(?)`. By putting the `?` in quotes, the database doesn't realize that you're dealing with a parameter.

Comment: ok, i'll try, but simpler query works fine with  `upper('?')`